# Sort an Array twice or fine-tune array using php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Lets assume I have a soccer league array:

```
  $array = [
    'teamId1' => 
    [
         'games' => 7,
         'wins' => 2,
         'loss' => 4,
         'duals' => 1,
         'point' => 7
    ],
    'teamId2' => 
    [
         'games' => 7,
         'wins' => 3,
         'loss' => 1,
         'duals' => 3,
         'point' => 12
    ],
    'teamId3' => 
    [
         'games' => 7,
         'wins' => 4,
         'loss' => 3,
         'duals' => 0,
         'point' => 12
    ],
    'teamId4' => 
    [
         'games' => 7,
         'wins' => 6,
         'loss' => 0,
         'duals' => 1,
         'point' => 19
    ],
    'teamId5' => 
    [
         'games' => 7,
         'wins' => 3,
         'loss' => 2,
         'duals' => 2,
         'point' => 11
    ],
.
.
.
    'teamId18' => 
    [
         'games' => 7,
         'wins' => 5,
         'loss' => 0,
         'duals' => 2,
         'point' => 17
    ],
 ];
```

and I want to sort this `By POINT DESC`; so I did use this function to sort my array by point:

```
function sortArray($array, $on, $order=SORT_ASC)
{

    $new_array = array();
    $sortable_array = array();

    if (count($array) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v)
        {
            if (is_array($v))
            {
                foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2)
                {
                    if ($k2 == $on)
                    {
                        $sortable_array[$k] = $v2;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $sortable_array[$k] = $v;
            }
        }

        switch ($order) {
            case SORT_ASC:
                asort($sortable_array);
                break;
            case SORT_DESC:
                arsort($sortable_array);
                break;
        }

        foreach ($sortable_array as $k => $v)
        {
            $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
        }
    }

    return $new_array;
}

$sortByPoint = sortArray($result, 'point', SORT_DESC);
```

Ok, now I have an array sorted by point, but now I need something like `fine tune` my array to reorder array in which `when two-or more- teams have same point, the team/s with more wins come before other`.

I know I can loop through sorted array and do something, but I'm sure there's shorter and tricky way to do that.

Does anyone any idea about that?

***Thanks in Advance***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to write a specific sort for this.  Using `usort()`, you can add layers of complexity to the conditions as you need it in a simple function...

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    if ( $a['point'] == $b['point'] ){
        // Sort by wins (descending)
        return $b['wins'] - $a['wins'];
    }
    // Sort by points descending
    return  $b['point'] - $a['point'] ;
});

print_r($array);
```

This sorts the actual array, so output `$array`.

You could expand it further by saying if the same number of wins, sort by losses etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as I need  `array keys`, I used `uasort` and that’s my answer.